# Processes listed as (bash) in ps despite instantly monitoring for them

Tags: bash, awk, process, background-process, ps

I'm trying to get some process information for short-lived processes, so I made a test script to help me.

I start up a background task that runs a continuous loop, piping the output of `ps` to `awk` to look for new processes.  The loop runs as fast as the processor will allow it to.  To test my program, I start my script, then run a few background `sleep` tasks.  Like this:

```
watchPIDs 10
sleep 1&
sleep 2&
sleep 3&
```

The `10` above means to let my script run for 10 seconds.  Despite the loop running as fast as the processor will let it, I think some of the sleep commands "live and die" before something registers, and it is messing-up my results...  Sometimes I see the `sleep 1` process in the above example displayed as `(bash)` (with parenthesis around `bash`) instead of `sleep 1`.

Googling the parenthesis nomenclature turns up [the following](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch38_07.htm):

> The parentheses indicate that the command overwrote its name, or that
> ps could not find the name, and that ps is printing instead the
> "accounting name."

I'm not quite sure if that's applicable here, or maybe I'm not understanding something...  It could be some error in my script that I don't understand... Otherwise, why don't I always get the name `sleep 1` for that process, when I'm almost certain that my script runs fast enough to "see" that process before it dies (after all, it does get the right `PID` for that process)?

Here is my code (mostly `awk`):

```
watchPIDs()
{
    [ "${1}" ] || { echo "No time duration specified, exiting..."; return -1; }
    set +bm
    end=$(( `date +%s` + ${1} ))
    {
        while [ `date +%s` -lt ${end} ]; do ps -o pid=,ppid=,pgid=,command=; done |
        exec awk ' BEGIN { fmt = "%-10.10s%-10.10s%-10.10s %-.70s\n"; }
        {
            old=0
            for ( pid in pids ) if ( pids[pid] == $1 ) { old = 1; break; }
            if ( old == 0 ) {
                pids[i++] = $1
                match($0, " *" $1 " +" $2 " +" $3 " " )
                pidInfo[i-1] = sprintf(fmt, $1, $2, $3, substr($0, RLENGTH))
            }
        } END {
            print ""
            printf fmt, "PID", "PPID", "PGID", "Command"
            for ( j = 0; j < i; j++ ) printf "%s", pidInfo[j]
        }' &
    } 2>/dev/null
}
```

Example output, with the test case listed above:

```
PID       PPID      PGID       Command
62246     62245     62246       -bash
62573     62246     62246       -bash
62574     62246     62246       awk  BEGIN { fmt = "%-10.10s%-10.10s%-10.10s %-.70s\n"; }\012        
63097     62246     62246       (bash)
63552     62246     62246       sleep 2
63985     62246     62246       sleep 3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be running your loop in the foreground and piping it so a subshell that'll run in the background calling awk but then (`exec`) replacing your current process with that subshell. I'm honestly not sure what the net effect of that is but you certainly shouldn't have `2>/dev/null` in there while debugging, if at all, and you could run it with `bash -x watchPIDs 10` to actually see what it's doing.

In any case, try this (untested as my `ps` doesn't have a `-o` option):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

watchPIDs()
{
    [ "${1}" ] || { echo "No time duration specified, exiting..." >&2; return 1; }

    {
        set +bm
        end=$(( $(date +%s) + $1 ))
        while (( $(date +%s) < $end )); do ps -o pid=,ppid=,pgid=,command=; done |
        awk ' BEGIN { fmt = "%-10.10s%-10.10s%-10.10s %-.70s\n"; }
        {
            old=0
            for ( pid in pids ) if ( pids[pid] == $1 ) { old = 1; break; }
            if ( old == 0 ) {
                pids[++i] = $1
                match($0, " *" $1 " +" $2 " +" $3 " " )
                pidInfo[i] = sprintf(fmt, $1, $2, $3, substr($0, RLENGTH))
            }
        } END {
            print ""
            printf fmt, "PID", "PPID", "PGID", "Command"
            for ( j = 1; j <= i; j++ ) print pidInfo[j]
        }'
    } &
}

watchPIDS "$@"
```

where I'm just moving your loop into the background with the awk command you're piping it to and tidying up a couple of other things.

Obviously if this really is stored in a shell script you could just call the function in the background.

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup!  The `exec` is mainly a bit of leftover code from an earlier version, where I stored the PID of the overall background process and either side of the pipe, and used a trap as the means to stop the script (now I just use `date +%s`).  I probably don't need it anymore.

Comment: You're welcome. I think the script I posted will do exactly what you want, please try it and let us know.

Answer (score 1):

To run `sleep`, Bash would first call [fork()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and in the child process it then calls [execve()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) to replace itself with `sleep`. So between `fork` and `execve` the child process name would still be `bash`.

(I have no idea who added the parentheses though.)

Comment: Thanks, so many I'm actually catching the process *too early*, not *too late*?  Good info, maybe I will make my script consider updated names (either replace the existing one or track them in two columns).